# SSIS - How do I read an Excel file STARTING from a specific row?

Tags: excel, ssis

The Excel file I receive is very "irregular" ... the first few rows are just descriptions and random information.

I want to start reading the file from row #17 and ONLY visible rows.

Row 17 is the header for the columns (like a normal table).

Is such a thing even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the excel connection you can set `openRowset`, selecting cells from your sheet like Excel,
Example: `openRowset: Sheet1$A17:f30`

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908460) add the script counter to your package then you can do a conditional split task for `MyCounter > 17`, if you do this straight after the import it should contain the correct rows.

I'm not sure what you mean by visible rows though. If you get rows that are fully Null then you can always add that to the condition.

Answer (score 0):

The excel file can be queried like sql statement. In your data flow task, take excel source set the conncetion manager as excel then data access mode as sql command. write the query on excel.

Example

Consider your worksheet name as Sheet1, having columns ID, Name, Dept and your data starts from 17 write the query like this

SELECT [ID],[Name],[Dept] from [Sheet1$A17:C65536] Where [ID] is not null.

This query selects data from row 17 to end of the excel until where data exists.

If your header row is A17 dont forget to check "first row has column names" in connection manager.

Answer (score 0):

I have created 2 variable one for File Name and other for Sheet Name and store the values from “for each loop” container to it.
[image]

I have made an Excel Connection manager and then take the sheet Name from variable which I have created in variable:

[image]

Now I have select Data Access mode as “SQL command from variable”.And then Select variable Name from drop down.
I have to read data from query_2 which I have created in Variable and in which i have used sheet name as variable "SELECT * FROM "+"["+REPLACE(@[User::FileName],".XLSX","$A35:R]")` to Select the range of data which is available in sheet .

Answer (score -1):

Click [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2176/dynamically-find-where-table-data-starts-in-excel-using-ssis/) for a clear explanation with example